# have been to China twice Vs have gone to China twice?

Tags: present-perfect

We can say *I’ve been to China twice.* But can we say *I have gone to China twice*?
Is it true? Is there any difference, or can they be used in the same situations?

Answer (score 4):

If you take a plane to China, and you are stopped at the Chinese airport because of problems with your visa, then you have gone to China, but you haven’t been to China.

In most cases, both sentences are correct, but “going” is travelling to the country, and being to China is about being in the country.

Comment: Umm. I tentatively up-vote your answer - but I don't think we can be too hard and fast about this distinction. I am, though, inclined to agree that having "gone to" a place suggests that the visit may have been for a more limited purpose, and perhaps shorter duration, than would be the case had one "been to" the same.